Python PDF manipulation to dynamically add x number of Page Templates to my output PDF
I have created an input.pdf using Adobe Pro that has a Page Template which contains text, controls & images.
I can successfully add the Page Template multiple times using MouseUp Javascript action attached to a button.  However, I need to programmatically be able to do the same thing in a python program and add the Page Template x number of times based on the number of items the user wants to generate.
Is there an easy way to do this in python?
I found using PdfWriter with the clone_from option was the only thing that worked as far as making sure all of my controls and their javascript Actions were there as well as retaining the document level javascript. Perfect!
def find_template_page(template_name):
        for page_number, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
            if "/Annots" in page:
                for annot in page["/Annots"]:
                    annot_obj = annot.get_object()
                    if annot_obj.get("/T") == template_name:
                        return page_number
        return None

reader = PdfReader(input_file)
writer = PdfWriter(clone_from=input_file)

Now, I'm struggling to first, find the Page Template in the PdfReader object and then add it x times to the PdfWriter object, making sure the controls and their Action level javascript all still remain with each addition of the Page Template to writer.
The find_template_page function doesn't seem to find the Page Template if it's set to invisible, which I need it to be in the source input.pdf.

You can use the PyPDF2 Package for this problem. Please do see the following code snippets.
https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/2m2k6/
Make sure to install this package before execution.
https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

Thank you @Farrukh, but I was staying away from PyPDF2 in favor of pypdf, even though the code is probably the same.
PyPDF2 was absorbed back into pypdf as per pypdf documentation
https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/meta/history.html

Also, I'm trying to find the invisible template based on the template name.  It's invisible because I don't want to add it if the user wants 0 templates added.  I need 3 of the same Page Template added, if the user specifies 3.  And then I need to add another Page Template to the end after all is said and done.
ChatGPT gave me the code I added to the description find the Page Template page index, but it doesn't seem to work for invisible Page Templates.
